# Efficiently compress numbers in ASCII (using PHP or JS)

Tags: javascript, php, compression, ascii, coordinates

In a short amount of time, I ran twice into the same problem:

- I have a list of coordinates ( latitude, longitude in the case of geo-coordinates — or x,y,z in the case of a 3D OBJ file)
- the coordinates are stored as numbers written out in ASCI decimals,... e.g. 3.14159265
- the coordinates have decimals
- the coordinates are stored as text in a text file or database
- the whole bunch gets too large

Now, we could simply ignore the problem and accept a slow response or a more jagged shape - but it nags. A decimal in ASCII uses 8 bits (where we only   need 4 to represent the numbers 0…10) and many coordinates share the same first couple of digits... It feels like these files could be compressed easily. Zipping obviously reduces the files a bit, although it varies. Base-encoding also seems to help, but it turns out not to be as efficient as I hoped (about 30%)

*Using PHP, What would be a pragmatic approach to compress coordinates stored in text files?*

( Pragmatic meaning: reasonably fast, preferably using vanilla PHP )

Comment: Why 5 bits?  There are 11 possibilities (including the "."), so that's less than 4 bits.

Comment: But why don't you just store them as single-precision float?  That's 4 bytes.  (Or 32-bit integer, depending on your range/precision requirements.)

Comment: What is "too large"?... are we talking 1,000's of coordinates? 100's of 1,000's of coordinates?

Comment: Also, "we could simply ignore the problem" - I would strongly suggest doing that, unless you have some evidence that the increased data volume is actually causing a problem.  Adding complexity for the sake of it is called "micro-optimization".

Comment: @ Oliver: Thanks for the critical remarks! 5 bits was an error, I corrected it in the question. I can't change the storage, because the coordinates come in OBJ or CSV files and/or are stored in a CMS. Optimization will lead to quicker responses, faster drawing or more detailed objects, so yes – it's worth it! I'm aiming for a factor 2 to 10 decrease in filesize. Is that micro-optimization?
@ Scunliffe: for 3D-objects we're talking about 10e5 magnitude number of points resulting in files of between 1 to 20 MB

Comment: I wonder why my question gets downvoted. Even just theoratically, storing numbers in ASCII seems extremely insufficient. If I'm right, an ASCII character takes either 7 or 8 bit, while we only need 4 for each number — so around 50% of the space our file takes is wasted... Or do I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quadkey to presort the geo co-coordinates and other presort algorithm, for example, move-to-front and burrow-wheeler. A quadkey is often used in mapping application especially for map tiles but it has interesting features.  Just convert the geo coordinate into a binary and concatenate it. Then treat it as base-4 number. Here is a free source code here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx. Then use a statistical compression like huffman. The same algorithm is used in delaunay triangulation.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I should this mark this as the accepted answer. Could the quadkey be used on three-dimensional coordinates, or does it rely on x, y and ZOOM (not Z) coordinates? Burrow-wheelers and move-to-front are really interesting as they seem to make zip-compression more efficient.

Comment: Yes, of course you can use it for 3 axis, it's a bit like an octree. But I didn't tried it could be a problem with geo-coordinate.